# how to optimize this sql query on mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT Matricule, Nom, Section, Nom_Section,
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb1, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt1, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv1, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-21' and '2016-2-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb2, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-21' and '2016-2-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt2, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-21' and '2016-2-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv2, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-2-21' and '2016-3-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb3, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-2-21' and '2016-3-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt3, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-2-21' and '2016-3-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv3, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-3-21' and '2016-4-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb4, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-3-21' and '2016-4-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt4, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-3-21' and '2016-4-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv4, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-4-21' and '2016-5-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb5, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-4-21' and '2016-5-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt5, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-4-21' and '2016-5-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv5, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-5-21' and '2016-6-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb6, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-5-21' and '2016-6-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt6, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-5-21' and '2016-6-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv6, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-6-21' and '2016-7-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb7, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-6-21' and '2016-7-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt7, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-6-21' and '2016-7-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv7, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-7-21' and '2016-8-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb8, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-7-21' and '2016-8-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt8, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-7-21' and '2016-8-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv8, 
 (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb9, 
(select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt9, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-5-21' and '2016-6-3') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv9, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb10, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt10, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv10, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb11, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt11, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv11, 
         (select sum(Presence_Badge_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pb12, 
         (select sum(Presence_theorique_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pt12, 
         (select sum(Valeur_minutes) from presence t where ((Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') and (Motif in ('ABSI','CP','CMAR','CMAT','CNAI','COCH','FERI','FINP','DEPL','CODC','DELE','FORM','HSUP','MALA','VMED','ALET','RECU','ACTBAD'))and (t.Matricule=p.Matricule))) as pv12 
         from Presence p  group by Matricule;
```

i have attached  picture of explain query 
and this is my table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dePcR.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE `presence` ( `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_effet` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`matricule` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `motif` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `nom` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `nom_section` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT
NULL,
 `presence_badge` tinyblob,
 `presence_badge_minutes` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `presence_theorique` tinyblob,
 `presence_theorique_minutes` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `section` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `valeur` tinyblob,
 `valeur_minutes` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date_effet`),
 KEY `matricule_index` (`matricule`),
 KEY `pres_index` (`matricule`,`nom`,`section`,`nom_section`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=673810 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(date_effet))
(PARTITION p_jan VALUES LESS THAN (736349) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_fev VALUES LESS THAN (736380) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_mar VALUES LESS THAN (736409) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_avr VALUES LESS THAN (736440) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_mai VALUES LESS THAN (736470) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_jui VALUES LESS THAN (736501) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_juil VALUES LESS THAN (736531) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_aou VALUES LESS THAN (736562) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_sep VALUES LESS THAN (736593) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_oct VALUES LESS THAN (736623) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_nov VALUES LESS THAN (736654) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_dec VALUES LESS THAN (736684) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

i did create a partition range on columns 'date_effet' and two index one on matricule and the  other one is couvering index on (matricule,Nom,Section,Nom_section)

Comment: I would propose: change your data model.

Comment: holy crap dude. Maybe save a temp table?

Comment: my table is filled from an excel document

Comment: what u mean by temp table and how i do that Rogue

Comment: yes bro the group by is the one taking the long time is there any solution because i have to group the result

Comment: is there any relation between `matricule` and `nom`? Same matricule = Same nom?

Comment: yes bro same matricule have same nom

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Aa3x4 this is a pic of the result and how mutch time it take

Comment: then you don't need an index: `matricule, nom, section, nom_seciton`, `matricule, section` do the job, due `nom` and `nom_section` will be always the same

Comment: btw, pt1, pt10, pt11, pt9 and pt2 are the same sentence.

Comment: yes i know mcnets i just test with them i did not fill the hole table yet with all the dates  so i duplicate some date just to test with them

Comment: i don't know why but in the explain query after i created this index it's show less row to scan

Comment: explain select
    `matricule`,`nom`,`section`,`nom_section`,
    sum(case when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') then `presence_theorique_minutes`  else 0 end) as PTM01,
    sum(case when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') then `presence_badge_minutes`  else 0 end) as PTM02,
    sum(case when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') then `valeur_minutes`  else 0 end) as PTM03............. this is the syntaxe i use now

Answer (score 2):

First I'd add `Date_Effet` to the actual index. (First field in the index due you're really filtering by date, and grouping by `Matricule, Nom, Section, Nom Section`.)

Then I would change subqueries by `SUM(CASE(` and add a `WHERE` clause that covers all data range.

```
select
    Matricule, Nom, Section, Nom Section,
    sum(case Presence_theorique_minutes when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') then Presence_theorique_minutes else 0 end) as PTM01,
    sum(case Presence_theorique_minutes when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-21' and '2016-2-20') then Presence_theorique_minutes else 0 end) as PTM02,
    ...
    sum(case Valeur_minutes when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') then Valeur_minutes else 0 end) as VM01,
    sum(case Valeur_minutes when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-21' and '2016-2-20') then Valeur_minutes else 0 end) as VM02,
    ...
    sum(case Presence_Badge_minutes when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') then Presence_Badge_minutes else 0 end) as PBM01,
    sum(case Presence_Badge_minutes when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-21' and '2016-2-20') then Presence_Badge_minutes else 0 end) as PBM02,
from 
    Presence use index(Date_Effet, Matricule, Nom, Section, Nom Section)
where 
    Date_Effet BETWEEN 'MIN_DATE' and 'MAX_DATE'
group by 
    Matricule, Nom, Section, Nom Section;
```

In this case and due to the date range (20 to 20), I'd add a new field to the table. Something similar to `analysis_period`. Build this field as: [YEAR+TEORIC MONTH]

```
+------------+-----------------+
|    date    | analysis_period |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2016-01-11 |      201601     |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2016-01-21 |      201602     |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2016-02-01 |      201602     |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2016-02-25 |      201603     |
+------------+-----------------+
```

Then you can easily group by this field using a single `SELECT`.

Comment: 105 IDOULAHIAN JAMAL 9180 ZSAC MECA 0 0 0 0 0 0
this  one row it return only 0 in each field i don't know why even my database is not empty between this date

Comment: do you know which partition should it use?

Comment: you can change `from 
    Presence use index(Date_Effet, Matricule, Nom, Section, Nom Section)` by `from Presence PARTITION partition_name`

Comment: i tested many date range it only return 0 or null bro, my final query will use all the partiotions becauce i have to return the sum from each month of the year

Comment: i did tested on a partition now and it return null :(

Comment: select
    `matricule`,`nom`,`section`,`nom_section`,
    sum(case Presence_theorique_minutes when (Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20') then Presence_theorique_minutes  else 0 end) as PTM01
from 
    Presence PARTITION(p_jan)
where 
    Date_Effet BETWEEN '2016-1-1' and '2016-1-20'
group by 
  `matricule`,`nom`,`section`,`nom_section`

Comment: i return now i valid number from one simple query thx but i still have the time problem i will work on it  and tell u if it work for me